# BigQuery - CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE

Tags: google-bigquery, ddl, external-tables

How use `CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE` DDL statement in BigQuery?

Another big datawarehouses solutions like SnowFlake and Hive Based(Presto, AWS Athena...) have it, and its so useful.

Comment: did you see anywhere mentioning of `CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE` DDL? I don't think it is available in BigQuery yet. so you might want to make a feature request - https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187149&template=0

Comment: CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE is released today (10/14/2020), please check this out: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-definition-language#create_external_table_statement

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant, CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE is released today

Comment: nice ! thank you for update :o)

Comment: wow, that is impressive list in today's release!!! great job BigQuery Team!! thank you!!

Comment: @YunZhang Cool 

Comment: @YunZhang Its not possible set `{"hivePartitioningOptions": {"mode": "STRINGS"}` equivalent, like in `bq mk --external_table_definition`, and "AUTO" are default, wich to me is a impeditive yet.

Comment: @YunZhang Another important think to me, is `information_schema.columns` work with external tables too, like to native tables.

`bq show ` works fine with external tables.

Comment: @ÉmersonEngroff: I have prefixed "BigQuery" in the title for more clarify. If you don't like, please revoke it !

Answer (score 8):

**Update 10/14/2020**, [CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-definition-language#create_external_table_statement) is released today.

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE dataset.table 
OPTIONS (
  format = 'NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON',
  uris = ['gs://bucket/*.json']
);
```

---

CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE option is not available in BigQuery, but as an alternative you can use BigQuery command-line-interface to achieve this:

**Create Table Definition File:**

```
$ bq mkdef --autodetect --source_format=NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON "gs://gcp-bucket/*.json" > myschema
```

**Create External Table:**

```
$ bq mk --external_table_definition=myschema bq_dataset.bq_ext_table
```

**Documentation Link:** 
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/external-data-sources

Comment: I see that, but its not a standard in the area.

Comment: I agree. You can use BigQuery client API, if you want !

Comment: Yes, but i prefer something more close to ANSI/ISO standard for SQL, a standard de facto in the market.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem and I saw the earlier solution. It worked but with twicking. I suggested an edit since create external table is working on GCP big query console, but the edit is not going through. Here is how I created external table to read csv data in GCS.

```sql
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS PROJ_ID.SCHEMA_NAME.TABLE_NAME
    (
    col1 STRING,
    col2 STRING
    )
    OPTIONS(
      field_delimiter = '\t',
      format = 'csv',
      URIs = ['gs://bucket_name/prefix/*']
    );
```

Make sure that the dataset and the schema are already created