# Loading multiple files from multiple paths to Big Query

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

I have a file structure such as:

```
gs://BUCKET/Name/YYYY/MM/DD/Filename.csv
```

Every day my cloud functions are creating another path with another file innit corresponding to the date of the day (so for today's 5th of August) we would have `gs://BUCKET/Name/2022/08/05/Filename.csv`

I need to find a way to query this data to Big Query automatically so that if I want to query it for 'manual inspection' I can select for example data from all 3 months in one query doing `CREATE TABLE with gs://BUCKET/Name/2022/{06,07,08}/*/*.csv`

How can I replicate this? I know that BigQuery does not support more than 1 wildcard, but maybe there is a way to do so.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64217474/bigquery-create-external-table

and you can specify multiple buckets in options like  **uris=[gs://BUCKET/Name/2022/06/*/*.csv,  gs://BUCKET/Name/2022/07/*/*.csv, ...]**

Answer (score 0):

To query data inside GCS from Big Query you can use an [external table](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/external-data-cloud-storage#sql).

Problem is ***this *will* fail*** because you cannot have a comma (,)
as part of the URI list

```sql
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `bigquerydevel201912.foobar` 
OPTIONS (
  format='CSV',
  uris = ['gs://bucket/2022/{1,2,3}/data.csv']
)
```

You have to specify the 3 CSV file locations like this:

```sql
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `bigquerydevel201912.foobar` 
OPTIONS (
  format='CSV',
  uris = [
    'gs://inigo-test1/2022/1/data.csv',
    'gs://inigo-test1/2022/2/data.csv']
    'gs://inigo-test1/2022/3/data.csv']
)
```

Since you're using this sporadically, probably makes more sense to create a *temporal* external table.

Answer (score 0):

se I found a solution that works at least for my use case, without using the external table.

During the creation of table in dataset in BigQuery use create table from: GCS and then when using URI pattern I used gs://BUCKET/Name/2022/* ; As long as filename is the same in each subfolder and schema is identical, then BQ will load everything and then you can perform date operations directly in BQ (I have a column with ingestion date)