# How to Check if Data Exist in External GCS Table with Fallback using BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am running a query to determine the very next date to use in my sequential query, but I'm receiving an error.

> Error while reading table: matched no files. File: gs://my-bucket/some-dir/*

This query is going to be exporting results into files in the bucket, however for the very first query I need it to check if data exists and if it doesn't exist use a default value.

```
SELECT IFNULL(MAX(DATETIME(EVENT_DATE)), current_datetime()) as latest_date
FROM `my-project.my-dataset.my-table`
```

I've also tried the following;

```
IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `my-project.my-dataset.__TABLES__` WHERE table_id = 'my-table') > 0
THEN
  SET start_date = DATETIME_ADD((SELECT MAX(DATETIME(EVENT_DATE)) FROM `my-project.my-dataset.my-table`), INTERVAL 1 HOUR);
ELSE
  SET start_date = (SELECT MIN(DATETIME(EVENT_DATE)) FROM `my-project.my-dataset.raw-data-table`);
END IF;
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on your requirements a little bit more? Could you explain what you mean by "I need it to check if data exists and if it doesn't exist use a default value"?For example, what type of data are you referring to?

Comment: Specifically looking to see if the table exists and if it has at least one record in it. If it does, we will use the datetime column from this row. If either the table does not exist or there are no rows in the table, use the default value.

Comment: Based on my understanding of your comment you can refer to this  [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42859614/) ,[link2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74686645/17258510), [link3](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/samples/bigquery-table-exists#bigquery_table_exists-java) to check  whether tables present or not. If the table is there you use a count function to check whether it has any record or not. Eg: SELECT row\_count FROM dataset.**TABLES** WHERE table\_id='MY-TABLE' ;